# After try to reinstall windiws, and error ocurs

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, installation, reinstall

I want to downgrade windows from windows 8 32bit to windows 7 32bit. When I normally boot win 7 from USB, when it comes to choose drive on which I want to install the windows, after choosing the right one an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEoqP.png)
 occurs. Do you know where can be the problem? Is there any driver which can help? I have got Asus transformer book T100TAM.

Comment: Difficult to answer this question with the partition list being blocked.

Comment: Asus offers no drivers for Windows 7 on that laptop, so you would need to attempt using drivers for windows 8.1, I suggest trying the chipset driver package on this page after selecting Windows 8.1 32bit.....https://www.asus.com/us/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TAM/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 0):

use shift+f10 you will get command prompt there you can use diskpart
check if disk part has access to your disk , if yes then you can delete partition using diskaprt or if you dont have any import data means you don't have any problem to format complete disk then you can use diskpart and select disk 
and clean it

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 by default can't be installed on a eMMC Storage without providing same eMMC driver to Windows Setup. This model of computer, as i can see offered in 4 storage configuration.

- 32GB eMMC
- 64GB eMMC
- 32GB eMMC With 500 GB HDD
- 64GB eMMC With 500 GB HDD

If in your case you have a hdd than you can opt the hard drive as system drive, after backing up your data from it. Installing windows 7 x32 on eMMC is more trickier as it is not officially supported and there is not enough information and driver available. Do you tried clean installing windows 8.1 which would be better than OEM install.